# Mongoid Search in embedded documents in optimized way

Tags: mongoid

I have 2 documents Users and books

```
class User
  embeds_many :books
end

class Book
  embedded_in :user
end
```

I want to search for books on some conditions, Is there an efficient way to do that rather than loop on all users and for each user loop on its books to retrieve books that matched the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
embeds_many :books
```

that actually produces an array of hashes inside MongoDB and then wraps some Mongoid stuff around that array and its elements. So you search embedded documents just like you'd search any other array of hashes.

For example, if your `Book` has a title field then you could say:

```
users = User.where('books.title' => /Pancakes/)
```

to find all the users with books about pancakes. Of course that gives you a bunch of `User`s rather than `Book`s. Embedded documents don't exist on their own, they're just parts of their parent document, so you have to go through the parent. But, once you have some `User`s, you can extract the books you're interested in:

```
books = users.map(&:books).flatten.select { |b| b.title =~ /Pancakes/ }
```

You can also throw in an `only` if your `User`s are large and you don't want to pull whole `User`s out of MongoDB:

```
# Some versions of Mongoid will get upset if you don't include :id
books = users.only(:books, :id).map...
```

If you're doing this sort of thing a lot then maybe `Book` shouldn't be embedded inside `User`.